# How to import exported chat back into telegram?

Tags: chat, telegram, restore, recovery

I exported chat data in HTML format. the chat was deleted and now I want to restore it using the files I have exported.
can I do that? is it possible?
I saw that you can import WhatsApp chats into Telegram but WhatsApp exported files are in Txt format so is there a way to convert HTML format exported files into Txt in order to use that method and import chat into Telegram?